# Do I have to set ID value in hibernate entity

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate

Do I have to set the ID value in entity class in hibernate, When I don't set the value for ID It shows "Column 'ID' doesn't have default value". Datatype for the column is Decimal, but when I use same database in Oracle I didn't get error like this. I was seeing this error when I'm using MySQL. Could you give me an suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach is to define the ID with an autoIncrement type. This let's the database assign the next available ID to that field. So then you don't have to set a value from the code (which could potentially fail if another thread on the server attempts to create an instance of that entity at the same moment).

The resulting ID value will be present in the returned entity instance after creation.

For example you can define such an ID field using JPA annotations as follows:

```
@javax.persistence.Id @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers

Comment: Hi @adriaan I declared ID with JPA Annotations already and changed datatype in database with autoincrement.
I was working on migrating hibernate 3.x to 5.x and I wanted to connect to all database type. As my code was written based on oracle It was working fine as older version but It wasn't not working MySQL. As your answer worked fine, But I don't want to touch database side. Is there any possibilities to satisfy my requirement.

Comment: To help further please provide the DDL of the Oracle and MySql tables. Did you set the MySQL dialect in your Hibernate configuration? What error are you getting exactly?